# Django email digest

Tags: django, email, django-email, django-mailer

Is there an existing plug-in to produce daily or weekly digest emails in Django? (We want to combine many small notifications into one email, rather than bother people all the time.)

Django-mailer claims to support this, but I'm told it doesn't really.

Comment: Why, Django is not user level stuff. This is code.

Comment: yeah, I'm just thinking, maybe this is about using the code, rather than modifying it. Just asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [django-mailer](http://github.com/jtauber/django-mailer/) app of which I was not aware till now, so the answer below details my own approach.

The simplest case won't require much:

put this into your `app/management/commands/send_email_alerts.py`, then set up a cron job to run this command once a week with `python manage.py send_email_alerts` (all paths must be set in the environment of course for manage.py to pick up your app settings)

```
from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand
from django.db import connection
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

class Command(NoArgsCommand):
    def handle_noargs(self,**options):
        try:
            self.send_email_alerts()
        except Exception, e:
            print e
        finally:
            connection.close()

    def send_email_alerts(self):         
        for user in User.objects.all():
            text = 'Hi %s, here the news' % user.username
            subject = 'some subject'
            msg = EmailMessage(subject, text, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [user.email])
            msg.send()
```

But if you will need to keep track of what to email each user and how often, some extra code will be needed. Here is a homegrown [example](http://github.com/evgenyfadeev/CNPROG/blob/e560c528524f1c2ad4fbc8c73ee1482693e7b7de/forum/management/commands/send_email_alerts.py). Maybe that's where django-mailer can fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 3):

I've just released the [django-digested](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-digested) package to PyPI. It supports instant notifications, daily and weekly digests, and individual preferences for different groups of updates.